# PWM control of a water pump with a MOSFET - can't find the errror

Tags: mosfet, pwm

I have a 5 V water pump and a 5 V/2.4 A power source. These work together. Now I want to control it with a PWM signal from an STM32 board using a [FQP30N06L](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fqp30n06l-d.pdf) N-Channel MOSFET and that doesn't work - nothing happens, the PWM signal goes out but the pump doesn't seem to get the power and doesn't turn on.

This is my circuit:

[image: Schematic of the circuit]

The diode looks dumb but it's the only one I could find rated over 2 A.

I would very much appreciate help in finding the error.

[image: Photo of the perfboard with the circuit]

Comment: @All --- The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). -- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133153/discussion-on-question-by-retiredgoblin-pwm-control-of-a-water-pump-with-a-mosfe).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the signal (the gate-source voltage) was too low for the MOSFET to open up with this load. With 3.3V it didn't open at all, with 5V it opened a little bit (and heated up a lot), and only with around 9V it opened fully. This is probably because this MOSFET is counterfeit and out of spec - here's a tweet with more info by someone who had a similar issue: https://twitter.com/ExtElec/status/1494060721818198020

Thank you everyone for the help!